# Slice up an image and use <a> or just use <map> on the entire image?

Tags: html

Are there any major difference between using the html `<map>` tag to map links to certain part of an image as oppose to dividing up an image and use the `<a>` tag?

I've been told that using `<map>` is way faster and dividing up an image and link each different image parts with `<a>` is just more work, is that true?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "more work", do you mean more work to write, or runs slower?

Comment: If you devide up the image then that's more requests to the server which is never good + it will look horrible if the image loads in separate blocks on a slower connection

Comment: By more work i meant, you have to divide up the image and then code it to look as if it is one image as oppose to just map it as a single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a single image divided into multiple images can lead to formatting issues with the images not aligning properly. This can happen depending on browser or screen size which isn't easy to control. Also you're right in that it is more work to do this cutting and aligning. Using map would be more effective means because it's formatting/position will not easily change.

Among a few other reasons, I feel for that formatting/positioning reason alone the `<map>` tag would be a better choice.

Comment: I see. But what if I am designing emails or even responsive emails. I can't use the map method anymore? or is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png)

The reason why the images are loaded as a single image is to reduce the requests and therefore the load on the server.

You should consider this in your approach